# Cannot find an attribute ID for an element RequestorID for added SOAP (wsdl)

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, sabre

I have planned to consume Bargain Max Finder Sabre SOAP API. In Response it shows me two errors.

1.cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'ID' must appear on element 'RequestorID ,  Code:INVALIDREQ

2. Error Code: ttfhlp684 , Type: Server, Value:TOMCA

Instead of Attribute 'ID' i have ID_Context. How to fix these two problems?

Comment: Can you post the serialized XML request that gets sent to Sabre?

Comment: Please see the link for the serialized XML URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939866/cannot-find-an-attribute-id-for-an-element-requestorid-for-added-soap-wsdl-gen

Comment: The ID is a required attribute. 

If you are using a client utility to generate proxy classes, I guess it can be a problem with that, not interpreting the types structure correctly .

Within the schema file associated to the request: http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/shopping/BargainFinderMaxRQ_v1-9-2.xsd - I can see the ID is declared under an attribute group named 'ID_Group', and if you follow the path starting from the types under <xs:element name="RequestorID" type="UniqueID_Type"> - you'll get to it. Within the with your XML, Pj suggested a fix for .NET, if that helps

Comment: Also, make sure the value for PseudoCityCode attribute under POS/Source path actually matches your IPCC (don't use 'IPCC' as the value)